# Does clicking a link in Gmail send a referer header?

Tags: email, gmail, http-referer

This is mainly for privacy concerns. If I open up an email on Gmail (or any other email provider) containing a link to a website and I end up clicking on the link, does Gmail send out a referer header? (ie. Will the destination website know that I came from Gmail? And would they know the email address that I was using when I clicked on the link?)

Lastly, if they do, is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 3):

No, if you use gmail's web interface referrer header won't be set, but destination may still guess that you came from gmail.

Here's what happens when you click `http://example.com/something` link in gmail:
actual destination is changed to GET `https://www.google.com/url?hl=en-GB&q=http://example.com/something&source=gmail&ust=TIMESTAMP&usg=HASH`.
In reply to this HTTP GET google.com replies `302 Moved` with [Location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) header to redirect to actual link: `Location: http://example.com/something`. When processing this reply *chrome* will request something like this:

```
GET /something HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
... regular headers ...
X-Client-Data: %HASH%
```

If you make that request by typing the URL in address bar the request will be identical except there won't be that `X-Client-Data` header. It seems that this `X-Client-Data` header is set by Chrome while accessing Google servers and it seems that no such header is set when using non-chrome browsers. If you open your browser in incognito/private mode and click that link in gmail then `X-Client-Data` header isn't set and on server side it looks as if you typed the URL in your address bar directly.