# Server side email verification : google chrome transforms my URL including token

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express

I've implemented a Signup page using MERN (MongoDB, Express, React, Node.js) stack.

When a user fills in a signup form, an email is sent to the user with a email verification token.

To complete the Signup process, the user clicks the URL to authenticate their email.

What I want to know is that when I click the URL, the request goes to both URLs (original address - http://localhost:5000/api/users/verify?token=randomstrig and modified address -https://www.google.com/url?q=http://localhost:5000/api/users/verify?token%3DfE2LHiOHqbZmfDTHtD1db9qumgQpUoZZ&source=gmail&ust=1549531956198000&usg=AFQjCNEuNxOv5c9SOFPjDr-AVBiCX7uUPw)

I want to know why the browser transforms the URL and requests both of them.

The following code is node.js code that processes URL GET request.

```
router.get('/verify',(req, res , next)=>{
  const urlToken = req.query.token;

  Token.findOne({token: urlToken})
    .exec((err, token)=> {

      if (err) next(err)

      if (!token){
        res.send({message: 'there is no token'})
      }
      else{
        User.update({_id: token._id},{ $set: {verified: true}})
          .exec((err,user)=>{
            if (err) next(err);
            console.log(user);

        });
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: can you show us what code you are using?  when you say both URLs which other URL? You only show us 1 URL which is the `Google.com/`.

Comment: @Justin sorry, I added my node.js code.

Comment: Since you are using a specific `token` parameter I would recommend using `/verify:token` as your route and to get the parameter: `req.params.token`  as for the issue you are having, I'm not completely understanding the issue. Can you explain further?

Comment: @Antenna_ This Question & Answer will help you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082676/does-clicking-a-link-in-gmail-send-a-referer-header

Comment: @AmilaSampath That's what I was looking for! Thank you so much

Comment: @Justin I have figured out what it was. Thank you !